# TYPO3 Formhandler Markers USER_INT, USER

Tags: extbase, typo3-6.1.x

i am using TYPO3 Version 6.1 with formhandler extension. I try to use two custom markers in formhandler TS of type USER/USER_INT. These markers instanciate a extbase plugin. The first marker will be replaced by the plugin output. The second marker recieves just a .

```
markers {
    # Modify studio search marker
    studioSearch.settings {
        search {
            status = 3
            formType = 1
        }
        formValuesPrefix < plugin.Tx_Formhandler.settings.predef.trialTraining.formValuesPrefix
    }

    studioTitle = TEXT
    studioTitle {
        data = DB:tx_mbxstudios_domain_model_studio:{GP:trial|studio}:title
        data.insertData = 1
        sanitize = 1
        wrap = <p class="headline-4 red">Dein gewähltes Studio: <span class="black">|</span></p>
    }

    # Insert Calendar Extension
    calendar = USER_INT
    calendar {
        userFunc = TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Core\bootstrap->run
        vendorName = TYPO3
        pluginName = Pi1
        extensionName = MbxStudios

        switchableControllerActions.Trial.1 = calendar

        settings < plugin.tx_mbxstudios.settings
        settings {
            formValuesPrefix < plugin.Tx_Formhandler.settings.predef.trialTraining.formValuesPrefix
            forms.trialThresholdHour = 16
        }
        persistence < plugin.tx_mbxstudios.persistence
        view < plugin.tx_mbxstudios.view
        mvc < plugin.tx_mbxstudios.mvc
    }
```

Any idea whats happening here.

Thanks

Comment: What do you want to happen? What happens instead?

Comment: i would like that both of the markers will be replaced in frontend not just the first one.

Comment: Are you sure, `TYPO3` is the correct vendorname? You see it in `configurePlugin` method call in your `ext_localconf.php`